# Using CiviCRM shortcode (wordpress) for a profile in a popup

Tags: wordpress

I want to include a Civi Profile (newsletter signup) in a popup. I have tried many popup plugins but none seem to work. The profile just does not load. Is this possible and if so, please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have had success with [Popup Builder](http://popup-builder.com/) - the preview never works, but the embed on the page always works.  This is a popup overlay - which I assume is what you are looking for. The [free version](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-builder/) is great if you just want a popup on a page of your choosing - the paid version is great if you want the popup to come up on any page a first time visitor first sees.